# InstallJava::fail error when importing an image with a Raspberry Pi

Tags: import, java, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to import an image in Mathematica on my Raspberry Pi.

The code is simple but I get an error when importing:

```
$ wolfram
Wolfram Language (Raspberry Pi Pilot Release)
Copyright 1988-2014 Wolfram Research
Information & help: wolfram.com/raspi

In[1]:= SetDirectory["~/"];

In[2]:= i=Import["small.jpg"];
```

> ```
> InstallJava::fail: A link to the Java runtime could not be established.
> ```

This is the image I'm trying to import: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzSLr.jpg
It's 1.5 MB large so the Pi should have no problem importing it. Why do I get this error and how can I prevent it?

---

UPDATE:
I believe this is caused when the computer is running out of memory. I don't know a sure way to reproduce it but it keeps happening if I do other memory-intensive tasks on my Raspberry Pi. I'd like to know if there's a way to prevent this.

and I got this error:

> /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/10.0/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-ARM/WolframKernel:
>   error while loading shared libraries:
>   /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/10.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-ARM/libWolframEngine.so:
>   cannot make segment writable for relocation: Cannot allocate memory

Comment: I don't have a Raspberry Pi so I can't reproduce this, but I presume you do actually have the JRE or JDK installed and usable...?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with either the November 19, 2013 version or the January 29, 2014 version.

Comment: It seems imgur compressed the image, here is one uncompressed similar image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3hp98lgf31hm0r/small.jpg The problem is that sometimes I can import images just fine, but other times I get this error until I restart the Pi.

Comment: @shrx are you able to reproduce this problem with the most recent version of MMA on the RPi?

Comment: @bobthechemist will test when I have the time, but my Pi occasionally still has problems with Mathematica, causing unresponsiveness and reboots.

Comment: I have this message on Windows 10. Probably related to out of memory.